# New site design launched

Tags: discussion, design

Update 11 October (from Catija) -

Thanks for sharing your concerns about the design. We can tell that you care a lot about how the design looks. While we weren't expecting the response that we got here, we are discussing things internally and seeing whether there are adjustments we can make in response to your specific call-outs.

I'll try to get an update to y'all by the end of the week.

---

As you can see, the new design just went live! At this point, we are done with major revisions to the design (although you can still report CSS/styling bugs by starting a new post and tagging it with [design](/questions/tagged/design) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)). Thank you for your [valuable](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/german-language-site-design-and-logo-final-draft) [design](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1697/custom-german-language-design-and-logo-information-gathering) [feedback](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1724/german-language-site-design-and-logo-draft).

I have really enjoyed working with you all to create this theme. Thank you for being an awesome community, and I hope you enjoy the new design!

Comment: I have to say I couldn't figure out what the little dot and the extra bend are supposed to mean until I scrolled down the other thread about the logo design.

Comment: @phipsgabler: You are not alone. The new logo is impossible to understand without explicit explanation. (And I think it's ugly, but this is my personal opinion.)

Comment: It is a little confusing that it has been claimed that a different logo would be chosen: "I will be keeping the concept of the current logo (as shown here), with only very minor changes " from a comment to this post: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1742/15393

Comment: I for myself am quite happy with most of the design. The only thing that bugs me is that the favicon totally goes against the style of SE favicons in general, being light on a big dark square. It extremely sticks out from HNQ lists and similar.

Comment: There are a few prior examples - like Sharepoint, the international SO favicons @Wrzlprmft but I can understand that they are in the minority.

Answer (score 17):

Has no one noticed that the monochrome logo that is now in use was [negatively evaluated](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1740/1487), that is, rejected? The new logo is incomprehensible. Without explicit explanation, one does not understand what it is supposed to mean. It would have been better to stay with the old logo.

I made a [suggestion](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1745/1487) that was better received, but the best rated was [that logo](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1742/1487) that was already in use before the change.

Comment: On the danger of repeating myself: I don’t think that logos need to be instantly comprehensible. Many logos on SE and elsewhere aren’t and I can’t remember anybody complaining about them. I slightly would have preferred [this suggestion](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1741/2594) nonetheless.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Hubert's point is not about the (material) question, whether the logo is good or not, but about the (formal) question that it attracted a net negative amount of up- and down votes in the finding process.

Comment: Some of the comments here are getting out of hand. Please remember that design is a hugely subjective thing and you are totally allowed to have your personal opinions about it. What we do expect, however, is that you can discuss your opinions in an open and thoughtful way. Telling someone that their design is awful is not going to gain you much favor with them - it generally just makes people want to walk away wash their hands of the situation. If you have concerns, that's fine, but I need y'all to **keep it civil** while being specific and clear about the issues you're perceiving.

Comment: I don't know the old logo. But when I saw the German stackexchange logo, I guessed around what it could be. I had several different interpretations, in one of which the elongated dangling part with the round head at the end hanging down between the two outer legs of the objects reminded me of a certain anatomical body part. () I knew that this could not be the intended meaning, but once you see it, you can't get it out of your head.

Comment: @Alina: Haha! Jetzt, wo du's sagst...

Answer (score 13):

I think the DEUTSCHE SPRACHE in the background is really distracting. Can we remove it or at least bring the contrast down by a lot? At this point it seems more like an advertisement banner (I was looking for an [x] to close it)

Comment: I think the main problem here is that the size of the letters was reduced compared to [the final suggestion](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1727/2594) thus increasing the visual clutter. Mind that this is just and educated guess and I would have to see the difference in action to be sure.

Comment: Maybe a different alignment between the background lines could avoid that the leftmost column currently (visually) shouting [DSDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSDS). Other than that, I very much like the overall design.

Comment: I like that background. I think the design is all in all good.

Comment: I saw a German.SE thread in the Hot Network Questions, and I clicked it. I was immediately extremely distracted, hopped over to the meta to see if someone else had the same thoughts, and joined this meta to agree with you. I am glad that I am not the only one.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) It seems there are some editing artifacts at the right edge of the logo when viewing it with high resolution:

In Firefox on PC on my 4k monitor, the rightmost bend of the `ß`appears  to be cut off vertically. The image below is zoomed 500% to make it more visible. The black version here on meta looks ok on PC.

[image: right side of logo is cut off]

On my mobile phone a pale light grey vertical line is displayed in both versions, and there is also a shorter horizontal line at the bottom:

[image: mobile version shows vertical line]

As this is only visible at certain zoom levels on PC, I assume it is not intentional.
On my machine, it also appears on a screen with 1920px 1400px with a zoom level of 120%.

Comment: I have seen this on my desktop screen as well. On my machine, it seems to depend on the resolution whether this is visible or not.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for the effort put into this! It looks very good. I can imagine it was not easy to take into account all the different considerations and still come up with a remarkable and clean design. You did very well!

Comment: I agree. The design of this site is well done (I don't know the old design, I only know the existing one.) But you really should think twice about that logo.