# Falsches Logo beim Einloggen

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

#### German

Mir ist gerade eben aufgefallen, dass beim Einloggen ein anderes Logo verwendet wird als auf der eigentlichen Seite. Wie ich erst durch Nachlesen herausgefunden habe, soll der mittlere nach unten hängende Zipfel des Logos den unteren Teil eines Fragezeichens darstellen. (Ich behalte lieber für mich, woran mich dieser Teil des Logos erinnert.) () Aber unter diesem Zipfel sollte eigentlich ein Punkt sein, der auf dem Logo, das beim Einloggen sichtbar ist, jedoch nicht vorhanden ist. Ist das eine beabsichtigte Variante des Logos oder ein Fehler?

[image: Logo ohne Punkt]

Was das Logo darstellen soll, ist ohnehin schon fast unmöglich zu erraten. Aber wenn dann auch noch der Punkt fehlt, wird es ganz unmöglich. (Ich weiß inzwischen was das Logo darstellen soll, aber es fällt mir trotzdem schwer, das zu erkennen, weil mir zuvor beim Herumraten eine andere Deutung in den Sinn kam, die nun nicht mehr aus meinem Kopf verschwinden will.)

#### English Summary

When logging in, the dot of the logo is missing.

Comment: [Diskussion](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1752/new-site-design-launched) zum Logo.

Comment: Dass der Punkt fehlt, sieht mir nach einem Bug aus.

Comment: Wenn das ein Bug ist, wo muss man den melden, wenn man erreichen will, das er behoben wird?

Comment: @Alina: Das hier ist schon der richtige Ort. Ich habe das Tag gesetzt, dass die Aufmerksamkeit der Verantwortlichen auf sich ziehen sollte und eine Zusammenfassung auf Englisch hinzugefügt, damit klar ist, worum es geht.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the report - I've updated the image!